# Почему уточняющие члены обособлены запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, уточнения

Пример задан из книги 8 класса (§ 52. Обособленные уточняющие члены предложения).

Пример такой:
"Всюду, и вверху и внизу, пели жаворонки" (А. Чехов).

Почему "и в верху и внизу" выделены запятыми?
Во-первых, **всюду** – обобщающее слово.
Во-вторых, союз **и** не одиночный, так что его нужно выделить.

Объясните, пожалуйста!

Comment: «Почему "и в верху и внизу" выделены запятыми? Во-первых, всюду обобщающее слово. Во-вторых, союз и не одиночный, так что его нужно выделить». Это цитата?

Answer (score 1):

Автор вопроса, вероятно, спрашивает, почему здесь не применяется стандартная схема оформления предложений с обобщающим словом:  *Всюду: **и вверху, и внизу** – пели жаворонки.*

Посмотрим оформление текста у Чехова:

*Был теплый, ясный день. В первый раз выгнали скотину, и около стада ходили девушки и бабы, одетые по-праздничному. Бурый бык ревел, радуясь свободе, и рыл передними ногами землю. **Всюду, и вверху, и внизу, пели жаворонки.***

Мы видим, что авторский вариант отличается от учебного текста, но оба варианта возможны. Кроме того, в обоих случаях ряд обособлен запятыми, а не выделен двоеточием и тире. Почему же так?

**Пояснение**

1. [Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101) (Розенталь)

Пункт 2. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом И, запятая не ставится, если образуется **тесное смысловое единство:** *кругом было и светло и зелено.* Такие смысловые единства образуют слова с ассоциативными (часто антонимическими) связями или фразеологизмы: *и зимой и летом; и стихи и проза; и день и ночь; и туда и сюда.*

В то же время вопрос о смысловом единстве может **решаться автором**. У Чехова: *Всюду, и вверху, и внизу, пели жаворонки.* Как мы видим, здесь запятая поставлена между однородными членами, то есть сохраняется перечислительная интонация, смысловое единство не обозначено. Но в учебных пособиях возможен такой вариант: *Всюду, и вверху и внизу, пели жаворонки.*

2. Если однородный ряд состоит только из двух членов, связанных повторяющимися союзами, то он при наличии обобщающего слова **может обособляться запятыми.**

Стандартная схема оформления выглядит так:

*ВСЁ вокруг: и дорога, и жнивьё, и воздух – сияло от низкого вечернего солнца. ПОВСЮДУ: в кустах, в траве – запели, зачирикали птицы.*

Но в этих примерах или три однородных члена, или бессоюзная связь.

А это примеры обособления запятыми:

*Обе старшие девочки, Катя и Соня, стали зорко следить за мальчиками* (Ч.); *Каждому, приехавшему и пришедшему, они должны были найти и указать место для ночлега* (Ч.); *Всюду, и вверху, и внизу, пели жаворонки; Всюду, и вверху и внизу, пели жаворонки.*

Таким образом, мы обособляем ряд из двух членов запятыми, если его достаточно легко можно **отделить от обобщающего слова** без применения таких сильных знаков, как двоеточие и тире. Чаще такое оформление используется при одиночном союзе И.

Стандартная схема возможна: *Всюду: **и вверху, и внизу** – пели жаворонки.* Но допускается только один вариант при отсутствии запятой между однородными членами: *Всюду, **и вверху и внизу**, пели жаворонки.* И тогда становится понятным, почему в учебном тексте нет запятой (в данном случае важна однозначность выбора).

Comment: @Александр Стрелец   Спасибо, Александр, за все правки, за ваше внимание и, как я надеюсь, понимание обсуждаемых тем. В частности, этот вопрос никому не показался интересным, никто не захотел на него ответить. А ведь он в какой-то мере дискуссионный (особенно в части оформления предложений с обобщающим словом). Любопытно, что его задают школьники, у которых восприятие правил письма еще не стало шаблонным, поэтому нестандартное оформление (в обход правил) не кажется обычным делом.

Comment: Да, вопрос хороший. С праздником, Sharon! Пусть чувства, мысли, тело и душа живут в гармонии!

Comment: Спасибо! На праздник я подарила себе книгу Эльчин Сафарли "Рецепты счастья. Дневник восточного кулинара". Он вроде бы известный писатель, книги его я постоянно вижу на полках с новинками, но как-то не решалась к ним подступиться. А вот эта чем-то привлекла меня, с душой написана. Обрести счастье  через нечто материальное? Что ж, неплохая идея, почему бы не попробовать. И вам я тоже желаю обрести гармонию и найти свой счастливый рецепт.

Comment: Александра из Питера на вас нету, Sharon (смотрите вторую строчку первого комментария)! ;)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Артем, я посмотрела: хорошая такая строчка в первом комментарии, правильная. Чем же она не понравилась вам, а то я не могу догадаться. Может, вы другую строчку имеете в виду (из третьего комментария)? Ну там типа надо было написать "Эльчина Сафарли",  но я подумала, что и так сойдет.

Comment: Я про "в частности", Sharon.

Comment: И что? Вводное слово, так в справочнике написано. Не обособляется в качестве наречия только в особом случае http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_132

Comment: Да я не про обособление, а про уместность его употребления без произнесённого вслух обобщающего понятия.

Comment: Хотя, вы знаете, всё-таки я неправ. Посмотрел сейчас получше и понял, что Александр говорит о необходимости такого обобщающего понятия именно для "в том числе", а для "в частности" его может и не быть. Простите!